# How to create a color image from matrix?

Tags: r, image, matrix

I got 500x500 double matrix and I am unable to convert it to image with image() function - it works, but result appears also with white lines which do not have to be... 

I got lot of values 0 and maximum around 3.7

If anyone can give some useful advice it would be great

Comment: Please post the actual code you've tried, and a **small** reproducible sample input matrix.  In addition, provide the operating system and image window type  you're using if not the default.

Comment: my matrix is called h, and i simply use image(h). My matrix -

Comment: My matrix: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XblBRsbsmyPePRTAnKo6ailY-gWBLY5jlY-VgC6fNRc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my result of `read.csv(your_data)` followed by `image(your_data,col=gray(1:32/32)`

[image]
What were you expecting?

Comment: Thank you,
Now I realized that Rstudio can't do this function like GUI